# Refresh without reload

Tags: javascript, refresh, reload

I have this div i which I add more divs with javascript.

However, everytime I add a new div the to div with javascript, it refreshes so for example a youtube video in on of those divs will stop.

Can I put these divs into the div without reloading it?

Comment: This is quite possible, but no one is going to be able to answer your question with the information you have provided. What are you currently doing now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must be doing something like:

```
myDiv.innerHTML += "<div>div content</div>";
```

That completely rebuilds all of the content in `myDiv`.  Instead, manipulate the DOM to insert the new div:

```
var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
newDiv.innerHTML = "<span>Some HTML</span>";
myDiv.appendChild(newDiv);
```

Comment: It adds it but, as text, not as code: http://piclair.com/eelmz
My code now: http://pastebin.com/bHxdruwR

Comment: Don't use `createTextNode()` to insert HTML.  You can just set the innerHTML of your new div.  I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Refreshing? Are you using a button (in a form, thanks RobG) with type of "submit" or a link to add the DIVs?  If so you can return false in the function you are calling to append the DIVs.

### HTML

```
<button onclick="return foo()">The Button</button>
```

### Javascript

```
function foo(){
  /*all the work*/
  return false; //No matter what, return false so you don't get a page reload.
}
```

Edit:  It looks like you're using a link.  There are a few ways we could go about this:

### Changing the href

You could change the href to "#" (called an *anchor* in HTML).

```
<a href="#">Foo</a>
```

This does not send you to a different page when you click it, but there are two caveats:

1. Always scrolls to the top of the page, or to whatever section you specified (e.g. #foo will scroll to the element with either an id or name of "foo".  This can be annoying for users.
2. Breaks our page for non-javascript users.  If you wanted that link to redirect to another page, non-Javascript users would consistently be stuck on that page.

More info: [W3C Page on Links (and anchors)](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html#h-12.2.1)

### Returning false using the onclick attribute

Returning false in a Javascript function will prevent a link from going to its original destination.  This also works for forms.

You could specify the action in the `<a>` tag's declaration to take, e.g.

```
<a href="foo.html" onclick="foo(); return false;">Foo</a> 
<!---The above "onclick" could also just be a function that always returns false-->
```

This method maintains any links we desired to keep for our non-javascript users, and won't move the position of the page.  However, this method also has some flaws:

1. Our HTML and javascript are intertwined.  This isn't the largest issue on the world, but it makes our code more of a hassle to update because, if we have more than one element we're attaching this event to, we have to then update it for every element.  This could potentially mean editing a lot of lines in our HTML document.  We can keep it a bit more DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself) if we separate our HTML and JavaScript.
2. Even if our JavaScript code is loaded in an external file and cached, we have to read this every time in the browser.  Again, depending on the size of your HTML page, this may not be a large issue.

## Binding events using JavaScript

A few Javascript lingo terms:

1. Event - Something that happens while a user is browsing a web page.  This can be a click, the mouse moving, the window resizing, etc.
2. Event Handler - A function that responds to an event happening.

There are many ways to bind Events to HTML elements using Javascript, but I'll keep it brief for the sake of simplicity.

```
<a href="foo.html" id="foo">Foo</a>
```

Here, we changed the a tag by:

1. Removing the onclick tag.
2. Adding an ID, making the element easily distinguishable from any other link (and any other element for that matter) we might be using on the page.

Let's add bind an event handler to our link with JavaScript:

```
function foo(){
 /* stuff we want to do to our div */
 return false; /* prevent page refresh */
}
function addEventToLink(){
  /* Set up a variable that we can use JavaScript to change attributes and event listeners*/
  var theLink = document.getElementById('foo'); 
  /* Set up our link to call the method 'foo', but ONLY when it is clicked on.
  * element.onclick changes the "onclick" attribute of the element */
  theLink.onclick = foo;  
}
addEventToLink(); //finally, call the method so our event listener is added to our link
```

Please note using `element.onclick` you may only set **one event handler per element**.  This is based on the DOM Level 0 Events specification.  If you want to add more than one event handler per element, view the breakdown of functions for both Internet Explorer and more standards-compliant browsers such as Firefox and Chrome at [Wikipedia.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOM_Events#DOM_Level_2)

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/77CLR/6/

Comment: The only case where a button will cause a re-load by default is if it's a submit button in a form. In that case, it is much better to use a submit listener on the form and do the work there (including cancelling form submission if appropriate).

Comment: @RobG `<button>Button</button>` does reload the page... http://jsfiddle.net/J2NDL/1/show/ ... but that's only because it's a submit button by default. I see.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas - yes, a [button](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#edef-BUTTON) is by default a submit button, however it will only cause a page refresh if it's in a form and causes it to be submitted. And it can be given a type *button* so that it won't submit the form either.

Comment: It's a link that adds it

Comment: Where does the link go? Post the code (as an edit to your question).

Comment: it's a javascript link; href="javascript:balbablabl()"

Comment: @enjikaka I'm not sure if Stack Overflow alerts on edits, but I hope my explanation helps.

Comment: it needs to be in a href="javascript:". It won't work otherwise, I'm controlling it with an Java Applet...